# How to upload specifically a tsv/text file to a shiny app?

Tags: r, shiny

So I want to add a panel in my app that allows users to upload a `.tsv`/`.txt` file so that I can convert it to a data frame, is it possible to allow users to add files with both `.tsv` and `.txt` as extensions?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

See `fileInput` from shiny. More information [here](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/fileInput.html)

With if-else, you can check the format and use `read.table` accordingly.